# Blackberry 10 Webworks with Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, ripple

We are starting a BlackBerry 10 project using version 6.0.0.2 of IBM Worklight, following official product documentation.

The docs about the building and running of the app refer to Webworks 1.x and Ripple.
Unfortunately I cannot find a way to make Ripple works with our Blackberry 10 project because we cannot start the Ripple services.

In order to run the app we are following these steps:

- Zip the www folder of the Blackberry10 generated project (www.zip)
- build the project in debug mode using webworks from command line

  `bbwp www.zip`
- After plugging a device or a simulator and installed the debug key on the device I run

  `blackberry-deploy -installApp -device <devie/simulator_IP> -package <BAR_file>`

Is there a smarter way to build and run the app?
What could be the reason why we cannot start Ripple?

**I'm using webworks v 1.0.4.11 with IBM workligh 6.0.0.2**

Is there a workaround to make our IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2  project run using Webworks 2.x?

Pointing WEBWORKS_HOME env variable to the Webworks 2.1 SDK folder we cannot build the Blackberry 10 environment.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight does not currently support WebWorkbs 2.0 together with BlackBerry 10.

If you'd like to try so anyway, you can follow this blog post containing instructions:

- [Worklight BlackBerry10 project with WebWorks SDK 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en)

Comment: Thank you so much Idan for your quick answer. 
Unfortunately I cannot perform the procedure described in the link. 
It stucks when I try to perform the ant qnx command, it says:
`Target "upgrade-webworks-SDK-2.x" does not exist in the project "Build and Deploy a Cordova BlackBerry WebWorks Project".`
Any suggestion?
Thank you